# Does BSON support an array of anonymous objects

Tags: json, mongodb, schema, bson

After digging around online, I have not been able to figure out if BSON supports an array of anonymous objects. The reason I want this, is for a logging system that has the following schema

```
{
  ERROR_LOG: [
    {
      message: "There was an error recording the file",
      code: 1133
    },
    {
      message: "There was an error saving the file",
      code: 1135 
    }
  ],
  FILE_LOG: [
    {
      message: "File 1234.txt edited",
      code: 5445
    },
    {
      message: "File transfer success",
      code: 2332
    }
  ], 
  ... etc.
}
```

It could be that this schema design is not efficient. I am open to suggestions for different schemas if anonymous objects are not supported.

Comment: What would be the context of the parent document? It sounds like these should really be separate documents to be honest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does.

Under the hood the documents will get a incremented name of '0', '1', ... but the bson libraries will hide that from you.

You can also mix the types if elements in the arrays:

```
{
    array: [
        {
            message: "There was an error recording the file",
            code: 1133
        },
        1234,
        "etc."
    ]
}
```

Edit:

Cribbing from the documentation here: http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/tutorial.html#bson

I think you should be able to do something like:

```c
bson doc[1];

bson_init( doc );
    bson_append_start_array( b, "ERROR_LOG" );
      bson_append_start_object( doc, "0" );
        bson_append_string( doc, "message", "There was an error recording the file" );
        bson_append_int( doc, "code", 1133 );
      bson_append_finish_object( doc );
      bson_append_start_object( doc, "1" );
        bson_append_string( doc, "message", "There was an error saving the file" );
        bson_append_int( doc, "code", 1135 );
      bson_append_finish_object( doc );
    bson_append_finish_array( b );
    bson_append_start_array( b, "FILE_LOG" );
      bson_append_start_object( doc, "1" );
        bson_append_string( doc, "message", "File 1234.txt edited" );
        bson_append_int( doc, "code", 5445 );
      bson_append_finish_object( doc );
      bson_append_start_object( doc, "1" );
        bson_append_string( doc, "message", "File transfer success" );
        bson_append_int( doc, "code", 2332 );
      bson_append_finish_object( doc );
    bson_append_finish_array( b );
bson_finish( doc );
```

Notice that the C driver made a liar out of me and you do need to track the 'index' names for the array elements.

Comment: edited the answer to include an example to create your exampledocument...  Might not compile/work but I think it should help.